# iPhone App : EncodeObject in NSKeyedArchiver trouble

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In an iPhone App, I have a `NSDictionary` object which has its key as `NSString`, and value is a custom object. Am trying to convert this to `NSData` for iCloud. 
I did this:

> ```
> NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
> NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]
>                               initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
> [archiver encodeObject:myDictionary forKey:@"mykey"];
> [archiver finishEncoding];
> ```

Now, the encodeObject line is throwing this exception (`NSDictionary` object 'myDictionary' has values in it. I checked.) :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ConnectionProfile encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f849350'
```

ConnectionProfile is the object I have stored as the value in `NSDictionary`. Should it implement `NSCoding` explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Yes. As I suspected, ConnectionProfile had to implement NSCoding. And now, the error's gone.